# Reset to unbound option in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

I have a dropdown menu in HTML as below, with a default option. I am using `ng-options` to generate the remaining options thus binding these and not the first with the variable `dropdown`.

```
<td>
    <select ng-model="dropdown" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
        <option value="">--- Select an item---</option>  <!-- default -->
    </select>                                   
</td>
```

Results in to the following HTML

```
<td>
    <select ng-model="dropdown" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
        <option value="">--- Select an item---</option> 
        <option value="0" label="item1">item1</option>
        <option value="1" label="item2">item2</option>
        <option value="2" label="item3">item3</option>
    </select>                                   
</td>
```

I need to support a reset button, which should reset the drop down to the default option "Select an item". Since this option is not bound to the model. i cant do something like this -

```
$scope.dropdown = items[0] // this would select item1
```

or even

```
$scope.dropdown = null
```

How can i reset my dropdown to the first option ?

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
   $scope.items = [{name:"ali"},{name:"reza"}];
  
  $scope.dropdown = $scope.items[0];
  $scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.dropdown = {};
    }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   
  <select ng-model="dropdown" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
        <option value="">--- Select an item---</option> 
       
    </select>  
  <button type="submit" name="button" ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, seems to work. But can you explain why ? At first i thought this would remove all the options from the dom itself but did not.